# storing coordinates in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I want to store coordinates into an array in javascript,
I am new to javascript and do not have an idea how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a number of ways to store x,y coordinates:

### Option 1 (every other index in an array):

```
function storeCoordinate(x, y, array) {
    array.push(x);
    array.push(y);
}

var coords = [];
storeCoordinate(3, 5, coords);
storeCoordinate(19, 1000, coords);
storeCoordinate(-300, 4578, coords);

coords[0] == 3   // x value (even indexes)
coords[1] == 5   // y value (odd indexes)

// to loop through coordinate values
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i+=2) {
    var x = coords[i];
    var y = coords[i+1];
}
```

### Option 2 (simple object in an array):

```
function storeCoordinate(xVal, yVal, array) {
    array.push({x: xVal, y: yVal});
}

var coords = [];
storeCoordinate(3, 5, coords);
storeCoordinate(19, 1000, coords);
storeCoordinate(-300, 4578, coords);

coords[0].x == 3   // x value
coords[0].y == 5   // y value

// to loop through coordinate values
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    var x = coords[i].x;
    var y = coords[i].y;
}
```

Comment: how to put 3 coordinates and retrieve them back using for loop

Comment: @Shaheryar - Updated to add three coordinates and loop through them when done.

Answer (score 5):

Well, let's say we make it simple, you want to store coördinates, so we have x and y:

```
function coordinate(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

This is how you create Objects in javascript, they act like functions. With this function you can create your coordinates. Then all you need to do is create an array:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push(new coordinate(10, 0));
arr.push(new coordinate(0, 11));
```

That's it basically

Comment: Thankks how to retrieve them back from array...like using a for loop.

Comment: Simple, for loop!

for (var = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   alert(arr[i].x);
}

Comment: *Awesome, thanks!*  I used this along with the js [`some()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp) method, to only add **unique** points to my array like `if(!arr.some(arr => arr.x+','+arr.y === x+','+y)){ arr.push(new coordinate(x, y)); }` (Credit also to [TechRepublic](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript.php))

Answer (score 2):

The push method would do the job:

> var arr = new Array();
>
> arr.push({ x : x_coordinate, y : y_coordinate });

You can then access them by using

`arr[0].x` (gives the x coordinate)

and

`arr[0].y`  (gives the y coordinate).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

These answers are not usable if you're trying to store a grid/matrix that you wanted to access data point by x,y values later.

```
var coords = [];

for(y=0; y < rows; y++){
   for(x=0;x<cols; x++){
      if(typeof coords[x] == 'undefined']){
         coords[x] = [];
      }

      coords[x][y] = someValue;
   }
}

//accessible via coords[x][y] later
```

Comment: Not true.  You can check for the existence of specific points using the js [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.  See my comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030229/storing-coordinates-in-array-in-javascript#comment110922745_7030306). (I found the `[x][y]` method to have other messy issues.)

Answer (score 0):

I saw a way to store coordinates using a Set. By using a Set you can store unique coordinates which can come in handy at times.

```
let coords = new Set();
coords.add(x + "," + y)
```