# JSON.stringify on php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have an array($coords) in php which contains some coordinates.

```
print_r($coords)
```

gives

`Array ( [0] => 80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579 [1] => 80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543 [2] => 80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899 [3] => 80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626 [4] => 80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579 )`

Then I used `$string = implode(",",$coords);
             print_r($string);`

It gave me

`80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579,80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543,80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899,80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626,80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579`

I passed this to Javascript like this-

```
    var Coordinates = [];
    Coordinates.push(<?php echo ($string); ?>);
```

now I want to stringify this so I used-

```
var JSON_Coordinates = JSON.stringify(Coordinates);
```

Now the value of JSON_Coordinates is-

```
[80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579,80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543,80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899,80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626,80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579]
```

But it should be-

```
  [[80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579],[80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543],[80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899],[80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626],[80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579]]
```

Someone please tell me where am i wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030229/storing-coordinates-in-array-in-javascript

Comment: Considering your code, I suppose `$coords` is more a string than an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [storing coordinates in array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030229/storing-coordinates-in-array-in-javascript)

Comment: So you got varied answers... be sure to accept one and close out your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use array_chunk to split the array to pairs

```
$arr = [80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579,80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543,80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899,80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626,80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579];
?>
var Coordinates = <?= json_encode(array_chunk($arr,2)) ?>;
// var Coordinates = [[80.233383421111,26.527489854686],[80.219159259839,26.510657834175],[80.230368593346,26.497855852629],[80.246672931234,26.510752593236],[80.233383421111,26.527489854686]];
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/977101)

Comment: how would I place coordinates inside []?

Comment: I have edited the question. Now it has complete details. Please have a look!

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see how the array is being established in your PHP code. Are they fetched as pairs or all in one big array?

Pretty straightforward. Just has to do with structure of the array you are converting to JSON.

```
$foo = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
// [1,2,3,4]

$bar = array(array(1, 2), array(3, 4));
// [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

I'd clean up the data server side, so you just have to JSON encode it, and then pass that client side.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your JS logic like that way. At this moment you are doing nothing in your code that will create a desired 2d array.

You should loop through whole array and increment counter by 2 to get 2 elements at a time and create a new temporary array that will push in your original arrCoordinates.

> Coordinates supply as array

```js
var coordinates = [80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579,80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543,80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899,80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626,80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579];

var arrCoordinates =[];
for(var index=0; index< coordinates.length; index+=2){
    arrCoordinates.push([coordinates[index], coordinates[index+1]]);
}

console.log(arrCoordinates);
```

> Coordinates supply as string

```js
var coordinates =  "80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579,80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543,80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899,80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626,80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579";

var arrCoordinates =[];
var inputCoordinates = coordinates.split(",");
for(var index=0; index< inputCoordinates.length; index+=2){
    arrCoordinates.push([inputCoordinates[index].trim(), inputCoordinates[index+1].trim()]);
}

console.log(arrCoordinates);
```

Comment: **I think you meant:** `++index`

Comment: sorry please let me know if anywhere I am wrong. I don't understand your meaning my friend.

Comment: thank you for your sharing a knowledge and explain me.

Comment: can you send your input array, before you do anything?

Comment: Butch your current array is quite different than question at present array so we should give you an answer according to your question.

Comment: My friend Here we all represent the logic as per your input array and based on your question.

Comment: this is original array($coords)- Array ( [0] => 80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579 [1] => 80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543 [2] => 80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899 [3] => 80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626 [4] => 80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579 )

Then I used $new = implode(",",$coords) So new one is 80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579,80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543,80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899,80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626,80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579

Comment: ok but your question array is quite different than present array right  my friend

Comment: still I open to help you.

Comment: Because my friend Butch everyone is not wrong based on your question.

Comment: See my edited comment now this one is same based on my question

Comment: so please tell me what do you wanted to do now please explain me in wording so I can help you properly.

Comment: I just want the array to be like this -  [[80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579],[80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543],[80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899],[80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626],[80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579]]

Comment: and what is inputted array for new result because it becomes bit confusing I got your output array but what is input array give me inputted array value I shall update an answer immediately.

Comment: Please review my answer I have updated an answer Please let me know whether it will help to solve your issue or not?

Comment: there is a spell mistake in your code coordinates have 'c' is small please look in my code you will get an idea my friend.

Comment: @butch got it my sentence?

Comment: I used small c and the error is same. Anyway thanks for your help. I dont know maybe the error is in my array.

Comment: @butch before apply anything review code carefully if here everything is running then definitely there are some typo mistakes in your code please look into that. I shall available message here I shall help you.

Comment: provide me your email id I will share the complete code there.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the array of coordinates, you can loop over it to build the desired output.

An alternative is using a `for-loop`.

```js
var coordinates = [80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579,80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543,80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899,80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626,80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579];

var newCoordinates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 !== 0) newCoordinates.push([coordinates[i - 1], coordinates[i]]);
}

console.log(newCoordinates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

According to your initial array, you can loop, split and then build the nested arrays:

**Initial input data:** `["c1, c2", "c1, c2", ...]`

This way, you don't need to call the function `stringify`.

```js
var array = ["80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579", "80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543","80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899", "80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626","80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579" ];

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var split = array[i].split(',');
  var lt = split[0].trim();
  var ln = split[1].trim();
  result.push([+lt.trim(), +ln.trim()])
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is giving me error -"coordinates.reduce is not a function"

Comment: this is original array($coords)- Array ( [0] => 80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579 [1] => 80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543 [2] => 80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899 [3] => 80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626 [4] => 80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579 ) Then I used $new = implode(",",$coords) So new one is 80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579,80.21915925983853 ,26.51065783417543,80.23036859334592 ,26.49785585262899,80.24667293123426 ,26.51075259323626,80.23338342111089 ,26.52748985468579

Comment: So, initially is an array of strings as follow: `["c1, c2", "c1, c2", ...]`?

Comment: yes but then I tried to change it to use JSON.stringify

Comment: @butch I'm going to update the answer with an approach using that input data: `["c1, c2", "c1, c2", ...]` so you won't need the stringify